# Facebook site integration -> fb-login button vs fb-registeration?

Tags: php, javascript, facebook, sdk

I have a website that I am writing.

- javascript SDK works
- php SDK works

HTML looks like the following:

1. signup page with fb-registration div
2. login page with fb-login-button div

Flow:

1. First time user ( which is registered to facebook), decide to signup. Signup page -> press "Register" -> fb iframe -> press "Continue" -> POST to PHP -> save user to DB -> reload page -> user is verified.
2. First time user ( which is registered to facebook), decide to login. ( never signed-up). Login page -> press "Login with Facebook" -> *blorp* happens -> ????

Question:

1. if my javascript SDK already know if the user logged in or not, why do I need the login button?
2. is it possible to use the website facebook api without facebook app?
3. isn't there a conflict between the register and login ?
4. what happens on the blorp ?? and following that question, is it just for getting the user information purpose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Display the login facebook button only to users that are NOT logged now with facebook.
2. You must be more precise, you have a website OR a facebook application, some API functions works differently.

3.4. The conflict is in your flow logic, you cannot login in your website a user that hasnt a registered account yet.

I suggest to get rid of the register, and use an auto-register and/or auto-login:

- user enter website
- Is NOT logged on facebook - show login to facebook button, return here after he logins
- is logged on facebook - show your own login button into site (you can auto-login as well, if you find his email address in your database, and he previous accepted your application).
- he press the login
- you check if is in database, login, if not - register, then login in the same request.